# How to sort this by month in MDX?

Tags: mdx, pentaho

I have never wrote a MDX line by myself, I have been using pentaho and a CDE Wizard to create some charts and it generates this code:

```
select NON EMPTY({Descendants([NOM_MES].[All NOM_MESs] ,[NOM_MES].[NOM_MES])}) on ROWS,
NON EMPTY({[Measures].[TOTAL]}) on Columns
from [museos_md]
where (${select_museoParameter})
```

I want to sort that result by a right mohth sequence, because I am getting the months in an alphabetical order. I also have a COD_MES measure that is the correct order of the months, I mean: NOM_MES->COD_MES, January->01, February->02 (coul it be useful?)

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution would be to use

```
Order(Descendants([NOM_MES].[All NOM_MESs] ,[NOM_MES].[NOM_MES]), [Measures].[COD_MES], DESC)
```

in MDX.

The correct approach would be to do the sorting in the cube design. I am not sure about Pentaho, but in Analysis Services you can configure the month attribute to e. g. use the month code as key, and the month name as name column shown to users, and do the sorting based on the key. This also affects the display of the attribute as shown to the users, where alphabetically sorted month names are a bit confusing.